# How to use gdal.FillNodata in python?

Tags: python, gdal, interpolation, nodata

I am trying to use gdal.FillNodata in python on a ".tif" raster. The nodata value is set to -3.402823e+38. Here is my code :

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import *

ET = gdal.Open("ET_sample_reclass.tif", GA_Update) 
ETband = ET.GetRasterBand(1)

result = gdal.FillNodata(targetBand = ETband, maskBand = None, 
                     maxSearchDist = 5, smoothingIterations = 0)

print result # return 0
```

This code seems to do actually nothing and I don't know how to define an output raster in python. I haven't found any example yet to enlighten me.

Comment: For gdal to write something to disk you need to flush/close the dataset. If you add `ET = None` at the end of your script this should work. You can see the same behaviour in the source code of the [`gdal_fillnodata.py`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_fillnodata.html) script.

Comment: Indeed it worked. Thank you. And is there a way to specify a new file as output or overwriting is the only option ?

Comment: Of course there is: You can either use the `CreateCopy()` method to copy a dataset and then write new data into it or create a new dataset from scratch with the `Create()` method. This is documented in the [GDAL API](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html). Not all drivers support the `Create()` method though, but GeoTiff definitely does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first comment turned out to be the answer here's the slightly longer version of it:

For gdal to write something to disk you need to flush/close the dataset.

If you add `ET = None` at the end of your script this should work and will write the new data to disk. You can see the same behaviour in the source code of the [gdal_fillnodata.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_fillnodata.html) script.

To create a new dataset, either as a copy of a existing one or from scratch, you can use the `Create()` and `CreateCopy()` methods as specified in the [GDAL API](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html).

The behaviour of GDAL is not really intuitive so I recommend taking a look at other [GDAL Python Gotchas](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas) you might run into.